# Count total number of rows of my table and print in console angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table, multiple-columns

I am creating a web app in which I have a table and a checkbox if I check the checkbox I want to show how many numbers of rows are there in my table,

like:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkall" ng-click="clickcheckall()"/>
    </td>
    <td>other td</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="somedata in table">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and here I want to print this

```
{{showcheckalldata}}
```

in my controller I have a scope variable

```
$scope.showcheckalldata='';
```

what I need to do if I want to print number of columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just assign the number of elements in the array,

```
$scope.showcheckalldata= table.length;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

   
  $scope.results = [{
    "agence": "CTM",
    "secteur": "Safi",
    "statutImp": "operationnel"
  },
  {
    "agence": "SMS",
    "secteur": "Safi",
    "statutImp": "operationnel"
  }];

  $scope.clickcheckall = function() {
    $scope.showcheckalldata = $scope.results.length;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


  <table>
     <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkall" ng-click="clickcheckall()"/>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Agence</th>
      <th>Secteur</th>
      <th>StatutImp</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
      <td>{{result.agence}}</td>
      <td>{{result.secteur}}</td>
      <td>{{result.statutImp}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <h1>Total rows are : {{showcheckalldata}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```